# Sticky table header in Internet Explorer 11 not working

Tags: html, css, angular, internet-explorer

I am currently working on a table view in my Angular application I want to make a sticky header to provide better user experience. To achieve that in Chrome and Mozilla I used the following CSS code:

```
div.sticky-table-head {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.scroll{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.scroll th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: lightblue;
}

.scroll td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <table class="scroll">
        <thead>
                <th>
                    <strong>ID</strong>
                </th>
                <th>
                    Column 1
                </th>
                <th>
                    Longer column 2
                </th>
                <th>
                    Column 3 that is longer
                </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Data</td>
                <td>DataDataDataData</td>
                <td>DataDataDataDataDataDataDataData</td>
            </tr>

            ...

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I need to achieve the same effect on IE 11 without using any scripts or jQuery, only Angular mechanichs. Pure CSS and HTML would be the best.

Here is JSFiddle presenting current solution: https://jsfiddle.net/bn5L1fhm/

Is there any way that I can solve my problem without changing too much of my code?

Comment: Angular is javascript so I don't understand why you say you can use Angular but not javascript.

Comment: DUPLICATED:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414609/fixed-header-table-on-scroll-using-jquery-flickers-in-ie11-internet-explorer

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12295

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility) and as far as I know, there is no standard way to achieve this with only CSS. You need script to achieve this in IE 11. We can only use `position: fixed` and listen for the scroll event of the page and use JavaScript to change the value of the **position** and **top** properties according to the current position of the viewport. The code used is like below:

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
var menuPosition = menu.getBoundingClientRect();
var placeholder = document.createElement('div');
placeholder.style.width = menuPosition.width + 'px';
placeholder.style.height = menuPosition.height + 'px';
var isAdded = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= menuPosition.top && !isAdded) {
    menu.classList.add('sticky');
    menu.parentNode.insertBefore(placeholder, menu);
    isAdded = true;
  } else if (window.pageYOffset < menuPosition.top && isAdded) {
    menu.classList.remove('sticky');
    menu.parentNode.removeChild(placeholder);
    isAdded = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ddcbaf;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #BFFFF3;
  text-align: center;
}

.sticky {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #989898;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  Title
</div>
<div class="menu">Home</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent luctus urna sit amet sollicitudin venenatis. Aenean odio tortor, varius vitae molestie eu, ultricies vel lacus. Nam viverra fermentum dapibus. Nulla at semper diam. Phasellus sit amet
    hendrerit sapien, non semper felis. Morbi augue leo, mattis nec leo sed, malesuada porta dui. Maecenas pretium eros quis lorem luctus gravida.</p>

  <p>Sed gravida quam odio, euismod accumsan mauris ornare quis. Duis sed condimentum justo. Phasellus ac dui eget velit bibendum viverra. Aenean porttitor commodo diam, quis interdum mi sagittis lobortis. Donec id ipsum dignissim, pharetra nunc sit amet,
    porttitor elit. Donec iaculis elit et enim interdum, ac laoreet lorem consequat. Sed eu elit ut quam pellentesque cursus. Integer sed condimentum est. Integer tempor placerat bibendum. Sed ut semper arcu, at porttitor nibh. Fusce vulputate pharetra
    tellus a laoreet. Cras imperdiet enim sed turpis adipiscing placerat. Vestibulum ut rhoncus mauris. In egestas ullamcorper dolor vitae suscipit. Curabitur non orci rutrum, iaculis ligula quis, sollicitudin neque. Aliquam dapibus dignissim tincidunt.</p>

  <p>Suspendisse at urna mauris. Vivamus eu lectus et quam viverra accumsan quis nec ligula. Aliquam sed mi sit amet arcu convallis bibendum id eu lorem. Sed pretium eget nibh egestas consectetur. Sed adipiscing, libero sed molestie laoreet, arcu tortor
    elementum ligula, nec commodo ipsum augue ut tellus. Morbi nibh mauris, facilisis vel bibendum vehicula, dignissim in tortor. Suspendisse augue urna, vestibulum at orci nec, scelerisque cursus mi. Proin congue eget justo et mattis.</p>

  <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis
    vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at
    metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent luctus urna sit amet sollicitudin venenatis. Aenean odio tortor, varius vitae molestie eu, ultricies vel lacus. Nam viverra fermentum dapibus. Nulla at semper diam. Phasellus sit amet
    hendrerit sapien, non semper felis. Morbi augue leo, mattis nec leo sed, malesuada porta dui. Maecenas pretium eros quis lorem luctus gravida.</p>

  <p>Sed gravida quam odio, euismod accumsan mauris ornare quis. Duis sed condimentum justo. Phasellus ac dui eget velit bibendum viverra. Aenean porttitor commodo diam, quis interdum mi sagittis lobortis. Donec id ipsum dignissim, pharetra nunc sit amet,
    porttitor elit. Donec iaculis elit et enim interdum, ac laoreet lorem consequat. Sed eu elit ut quam pellentesque cursus. Integer sed condimentum est. Integer tempor placerat bibendum. Sed ut semper arcu, at porttitor nibh. Fusce vulputate pharetra
    tellus a laoreet. Cras imperdiet enim sed turpis adipiscing placerat. Vestibulum ut rhoncus mauris. In egestas ullamcorper dolor vitae suscipit. Curabitur non orci rutrum, iaculis ligula quis, sollicitudin neque. Aliquam dapibus dignissim tincidunt.</p>

  <p>Suspendisse at urna mauris. Vivamus eu lectus et quam viverra accumsan quis nec ligula. Aliquam sed mi sit amet arcu convallis bibendum id eu lorem. Sed pretium eget nibh egestas consectetur. Sed adipiscing, libero sed molestie laoreet, arcu tortor
    elementum ligula, nec commodo ipsum augue ut tellus. Morbi nibh mauris, facilisis vel bibendum vehicula, dignissim in tortor. Suspendisse augue urna, vestibulum at orci nec, scelerisque cursus mi. Proin congue eget justo et mattis.</p>

  <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis
    vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at
    metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent luctus urna sit amet sollicitudin venenatis. Aenean odio tortor, varius vitae molestie eu, ultricies vel lacus. Nam viverra fermentum dapibus. Nulla at semper diam. Phasellus sit amet
    hendrerit sapien, non semper felis. Morbi augue leo, mattis nec leo sed, malesuada porta dui. Maecenas pretium eros quis lorem luctus gravida.</p>

  <p>Sed gravida quam odio, euismod accumsan mauris ornare quis. Duis sed condimentum justo. Phasellus ac dui eget velit bibendum viverra. Aenean porttitor commodo diam, quis interdum mi sagittis lobortis. Donec id ipsum dignissim, pharetra nunc sit amet,
    porttitor elit. Donec iaculis elit et enim interdum, ac laoreet lorem consequat. Sed eu elit ut quam pellentesque cursus. Integer sed condimentum est. Integer tempor placerat bibendum. Sed ut semper arcu, at porttitor nibh. Fusce vulputate pharetra
    tellus a laoreet. Cras imperdiet enim sed turpis adipiscing placerat. Vestibulum ut rhoncus mauris. In egestas ullamcorper dolor vitae suscipit. Curabitur non orci rutrum, iaculis ligula quis, sollicitudin neque. Aliquam dapibus dignissim tincidunt.</p>

  <p>Suspendisse at urna mauris. Vivamus eu lectus et quam viverra accumsan quis nec ligula. Aliquam sed mi sit amet arcu convallis bibendum id eu lorem. Sed pretium eget nibh egestas consectetur. Sed adipiscing, libero sed molestie laoreet, arcu tortor
    elementum ligula, nec commodo ipsum augue ut tellus. Morbi nibh mauris, facilisis vel bibendum vehicula, dignissim in tortor. Suspendisse augue urna, vestibulum at orci nec, scelerisque cursus mi. Proin congue eget justo et mattis.</p>

  <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis
    vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at
    metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent luctus urna sit amet sollicitudin venenatis. Aenean odio tortor, varius vitae molestie eu, ultricies vel lacus. Nam viverra fermentum dapibus. Nulla at semper diam. Phasellus sit amet
    hendrerit sapien, non semper felis. Morbi augue leo, mattis nec leo sed, malesuada porta dui. Maecenas pretium eros quis lorem luctus gravida.</p>

  <p>Sed gravida quam odio, euismod accumsan mauris ornare quis. Duis sed condimentum justo. Phasellus ac dui eget velit bibendum viverra. Aenean porttitor commodo diam, quis interdum mi sagittis lobortis. Donec id ipsum dignissim, pharetra nunc sit amet,
    porttitor elit. Donec iaculis elit et enim interdum, ac laoreet lorem consequat. Sed eu elit ut quam pellentesque cursus. Integer sed condimentum est. Integer tempor placerat bibendum. Sed ut semper arcu, at porttitor nibh. Fusce vulputate pharetra
    tellus a laoreet. Cras imperdiet enim sed turpis adipiscing placerat. Vestibulum ut rhoncus mauris. In egestas ullamcorper dolor vitae suscipit. Curabitur non orci rutrum, iaculis ligula quis, sollicitudin neque. Aliquam dapibus dignissim tincidunt.</p>

  <p>Suspendisse at urna mauris. Vivamus eu lectus et quam viverra accumsan quis nec ligula. Aliquam sed mi sit amet arcu convallis bibendum id eu lorem. Sed pretium eget nibh egestas consectetur. Sed adipiscing, libero sed molestie laoreet, arcu tortor
    elementum ligula, nec commodo ipsum augue ut tellus. Morbi nibh mauris, facilisis vel bibendum vehicula, dignissim in tortor. Suspendisse augue urna, vestibulum at orci nec, scelerisque cursus mi. Proin congue eget justo et mattis.</p>

  <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis
    vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at
    metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent luctus urna sit amet sollicitudin venenatis. Aenean odio tortor, varius vitae molestie eu, ultricies vel lacus. Nam viverra fermentum dapibus. Nulla at semper diam. Phasellus sit amet
    hendrerit sapien, non semper felis. Morbi augue leo, mattis nec leo sed, malesuada porta dui. Maecenas pretium eros quis lorem luctus gravida.</p>

  <p>Sed gravida quam odio, euismod accumsan mauris ornare quis. Duis sed condimentum justo. Phasellus ac dui eget velit bibendum viverra. Aenean porttitor commodo diam, quis interdum mi sagittis lobortis. Donec id ipsum dignissim, pharetra nunc sit amet,
    porttitor elit. Donec iaculis elit et enim interdum, ac laoreet lorem consequat. Sed eu elit ut quam pellentesque cursus. Integer sed condimentum est. Integer tempor placerat bibendum. Sed ut semper arcu, at porttitor nibh. Fusce vulputate pharetra
    tellus a laoreet. Cras imperdiet enim sed turpis adipiscing placerat. Vestibulum ut rhoncus mauris. In egestas ullamcorper dolor vitae suscipit. Curabitur non orci rutrum, iaculis ligula quis, sollicitudin neque. Aliquam dapibus dignissim tincidunt.</p>

  <p>Suspendisse at urna mauris. Vivamus eu lectus et quam viverra accumsan quis nec ligula. Aliquam sed mi sit amet arcu convallis bibendum id eu lorem. Sed pretium eget nibh egestas consectetur. Sed adipiscing, libero sed molestie laoreet, arcu tortor
    elementum ligula, nec commodo ipsum augue ut tellus. Morbi nibh mauris, facilisis vel bibendum vehicula, dignissim in tortor. Suspendisse augue urna, vestibulum at orci nec, scelerisque cursus mi. Proin congue eget justo et mattis.</p>

  <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis
    vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at
    metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent luctus urna sit amet sollicitudin venenatis. Aenean odio tortor, varius vitae molestie eu, ultricies vel lacus. Nam viverra fermentum dapibus. Nulla at semper diam. Phasellus sit amet
    hendrerit sapien, non semper felis. Morbi augue leo, mattis nec leo sed, malesuada porta dui. Maecenas pretium eros quis lorem luctus gravida.</p>

  <p>Sed gravida quam odio, euismod accumsan mauris ornare quis. Duis sed condimentum justo. Phasellus ac dui eget velit bibendum viverra. Aenean porttitor commodo diam, quis interdum mi sagittis lobortis. Donec id ipsum dignissim, pharetra nunc sit amet,
    porttitor elit. Donec iaculis elit et enim interdum, ac laoreet lorem consequat. Sed eu elit ut quam pellentesque cursus. Integer sed condimentum est. Integer tempor placerat bibendum. Sed ut semper arcu, at porttitor nibh. Fusce vulputate pharetra
    tellus a laoreet. Cras imperdiet enim sed turpis adipiscing placerat. Vestibulum ut rhoncus mauris. In egestas ullamcorper dolor vitae suscipit. Curabitur non orci rutrum, iaculis ligula quis, sollicitudin neque. Aliquam dapibus dignissim tincidunt.</p>

  <p>Suspendisse at urna mauris. Vivamus eu lectus et quam viverra accumsan quis nec ligula. Aliquam sed mi sit amet arcu convallis bibendum id eu lorem. Sed pretium eget nibh egestas consectetur. Sed adipiscing, libero sed molestie laoreet, arcu tortor
    elementum ligula, nec commodo ipsum augue ut tellus. Morbi nibh mauris, facilisis vel bibendum vehicula, dignissim in tortor. Suspendisse augue urna, vestibulum at orci nec, scelerisque cursus mi. Proin congue eget justo et mattis.</p>

  <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis
    vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at
    metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>
</div>
```

And the closest approach with your situation I found is the solutin in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48410607/sticky-table-headers-with-firefox-ie/48412558#48412558), you could also refer to it.